# invariants of a finite group other than the symmetric group

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory, invariant-theory

Let $R$ be a Dedekind ring and consider $R[x]$. Let $G$ be a finite group acting on $R[x]$ which acts on $R$ trivially. I want to know if there is a general method to calculate $R[x]^G$.

I unfortunately have no background in the invariant theory, and it looks like almost all notes on the invariant theory that I find on Google discuss the symmetric group $S_n$ acting on $k[x_1, ..., x_n]$ the polynomial ring of $n$ variables over a field $k$. I'm not sure if my question would be answered in much later chapters of a typical invariant theory textbook. Even if I strengthen my polynomial ring to be $k[x]$, I'm concerned with a finite group action other than $S_n = S_1$.

Could someone guide me on where to start learning about theories discussing my question?

Thank you.

Comment: You can certainly reduce to the case of fields (in particular the fraction field and the residue field of primes dividing the order of $G$). The ring $k[x]^{G}$ is then finitely generated (Hilbert), and in characteristic $0$ all generators are in degree at most $|G|$.  Once you have the generators,  you can find the relations using commutative algebra. Modular representations can be more complicated, see https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/fbac/250d44d2fe6c2ae633b44c0237f3aa7dbb64.pdf for example.

Comment: What is the group action in your example? Often you can work these things out by hand or reduce them to some well-studied case.